# svg.draw.js: edit existing object

Tags: svg.js

I'm struggling with svg.draw.js. I can draw new shapes, there are lots of examples around, but when I try to re-edit some existing shape, I'm doing it wrong, and I cannot find coding example about it.

```
//passing SVG node to function:
function editShape(el){
   SVG.get(el.id).draw(); //nothing happens
}
```

Comment: maybe you wanna try svg.resize.js for that purpose

Comment: I wanna select new boundaries for that object using mouse.